# Use of pulleys in gearboxes

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design, gears, pulleys

I'm designing a simple gearbox with some fairly strict space constraints. I was wondering if having a belt pulley inside of a custom gearbox is a serious issue for the belt. Would it get worn down from metal shavings or gear lubricant? This screams bad idea to me but I figured I'd get a more experienced opinion. I've attached a picture to demonstrate what I'm talking about.[image: Pulley on same shaft inside of gearbox, can't fit outside due to motor.]

Comment: Have gears with internal teeth then the motor gets closer to the centre line keeping the overall size down. Check epicyclic gearing for one way to reduce space requirements.

Comment: Another thing you can do is consider a chain. The required size of a chain is significantly smaller than a belt for the same power.